# How does removing 3DES_EDE_CBC from java.security file allow HTTPS calls to server with RC4-MD5 cipher?

Tags: ssl, https, java-8, openssl, java-security

When a java 8 client code using Apache HttpClient called a https server we saw following error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:557)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at HttpClient.main(HttpClient.java:64)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        ... 14 more
```

It was found that the server had RC4-MD5 cipher and since this was not supported in Java 8, this error occurred.
Here is the result after running "openssl s_client -tls1 -connect :443" on the target https server.

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-MD5
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
```

So I edited the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms property in "java.secuity" file in JVM. I removed the option '3DES_EDE_CBC' from this entry.

Old property value:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC_40, 3DES_EDE_CBC
```

Edited property value:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 1024, \
    EC keySize < 224, DES40_CBC_40
```

After editing the java.security file, the Java HTTPS call worked.

**Question:** How does removing the '3DES_EDE_CBC' alogrithm from disabled algorithms allow this HTTPS call to work? How can I understand this better? Thanks.

Comment: For those who don't have $JAVA_HOME defined, use Debian or have HP gen7 with ilo3 - the file you need to edit might be this: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.security`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is typically that a server supports multiple cipher suites. Most likely the server supports at least RC4 and 3DES and thus enabling 3DES in your client was enough to find a common cipher.

Comment: Thanks @steffen-Ullrich . How can we see that the server supports both RC4 and DES? From "openssl" command I saw that it supports RC4.

Comment: @ShankarPS: try `openssl s_client -connect ... -cipher '3DES'` to enforce use of 3DES and it should work too. Also DES is not the same as 3DES.

Comment: Note that now `RC4` is recommended not to be used (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7465.txt)  and `3DES` is not among the possible cipher suites in TLS 1.3 anymore (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446#appendix-B.4). So in short while the config change solves the problem, there is a far bigger one (server and client updates) around the corner.

Comment: @ShankarPS You can alternatively use an online scanner such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to test your server. And/Or peruse your server configuration to see what it enables.